# Search for item in a CSV file using User-inputted Keywords

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I am given a CSV file which catalogs some 1000 songs, the data given is the `Artist`, `Album`, `Song_Title`, and `Duration` of the songs in seconds.

I import the CSV file by doing the following:

```
column_names = ['artist', 'album', 'song_title', 'duration']

track_list = pd.read_csv('/Users/Basel/Desktop/Class Files/JukeBoxHero/music-collection.csv', names=column_names,
                         header=None)
```

for reference, this is an example of a line from the CSV file:

```
Aerosmith,A Little South Of Sanity Disc 1,Falling In Love (Is Hard On The Knees),209
```

The function I am attempting to use to allow the user to enter a search term and get a list of all the songs which have the search term in their names goes as follows:

```
def findSongs(songList):
    searchTerm=input("searching for?")
    for songs in songList:
        if searchTerm in songs:
            print("-----------------------")
            print("Artist: " + currentSong['artist'])
            print("Album: " + currentSong['album'])
            print("Title: " + currentSong['song_title])
            print("Duration: " + currentSong['duration'] + "seconds")
```

However, when I try to call the function with `print(findSongs(track_list))` the terminal always seems to output `None`. My guess is that there is something wrong in the way I am structuring my for-loop but I have spent a lot of time trying out different variables and trying to use integer indexes all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def findSongs(songList):
    searchTerm=input("searching for?")
    songList = songList[songList.song_title.str.contains(searchTerm)].to_numpy()
    for songs in songList:
            print("-----------------------")
            print("Artist: " + songs[0])
            print("Album: " + songs[1])
            print("Title: " + songs[2])
            print("Duration: " + str(songs[3]))

findSongs(track_list)
```

output:

```
searching for?Falling
-----------------------
Artist: Aerosmith
Album: A Little South Of Sanity Disc 1
Title: Falling In Love (Is Hard On The Knees)
Duration: 209
```

updated version:

```
def findSongs(songList):
  while True:
    searchTerm=input("searching for ( exit to exit )?")
    if searchTerm == 'exit':
       break
    songList = songList[songList.song_title.str.contains(searchTerm)].to_numpy()
    if len(songList) == 0:
       print("No Song found ")
       continue
    for songs in songList:
            print("-----------------------")
            print("Artist: " + songs[0])
            print("Album: " + songs[1])
            print("Title: " + songs[2])
            print("Duration: " + str(songs[3]))
```

Comment: This solves my problem but is there a way to put this in an if-else context, however? The end-intent of having the if was to have an else prompting the user that no songs were found if there are no matching search terms.

Comment: @Banani720 i updated the answer with one that continues asking until exit is input and will let users know that no answer was found. I hope that helps, thx!

Comment: Yes and the answer makes a lot of sense conceptually as well appreciate it!